# eclipse project after exporting to jar doesn't work

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, noclassdeffounderror

I have 2 project in my eclipse work_space.
Project A:Source of Apache Tomcat by a little edit[and have some dependent jars].
Project B: A small project call one method[One method of project A's methods].

So when I used Project A in Project B(added to BuildPAth's projects) or test this method in project A that work. But When project B used exported project A's jar file DOESN'T Work(only remove project A from project B's BuildPath and add A's jar file).
Exception which throw is:

```
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tools/ant/util/FileUtils
    at org.apache.jasper.JspC.resolveFile(JspC.java:1602)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspC.setOutputDir(JspC.java:863)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspC.setArgs(JspC.java:276)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspC.main(JspC.java:241)
    at jspCompiler.pars(jspCompiler.java:65)
    at jspCompiler.main(jspCompiler.java:100)
    at maintst.main(maintst.java:11)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tools.ant.util.FileUtils
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 7 more
```

Where is problem?

**EDIT**

**Maintst.java**

```
import jspParser.jspCompiler;
public class maintst { 
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { 
    jspCompiler cmp=new jspCompiler();
    cmp.main(new String[]{"F:\\arshad droos\\Thesis\\secureBranch\\personalblog\\build","F:\\arshad droos\\Thesis\\secureBranch"}); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes this kind of problem rapidly occurs, because of the inability of eclipse to look for java files, rather it searches for class files. Me thinks, it will work, if you convert the full project A to A.jar and add it to the build path of the project B.

Comment: Thx I do that But no work. Same Exception.

Comment: Have you converted the full project in to a jar ? How did you do it ? Which tool u used for this purpose ?

Comment: I right  click on project A -> export -> jar -> and this options:tik 1th, 3,4,5,6,7th check box -> in next step 1,2,4th check box -> finish.

Comment: @Mirazaei Have you added A.jar at a physical location in B? or you just have added it in classpath?

Comment: You need to create a folder called lib inside your project B folder and then from there you need to add a.jar in your build path. Things will look much organized this way .

Comment: yes I add to B's libs directory and then add to builpath.

Comment: @Mirzaei In that case you must be getting compile-time error. Aren't you?

Comment: I add jspCompiler class to project A and can access it in Project B.So I think Problem isn't in build Path.

Comment: If it's just a warning, then you can try it out now and see whether this works.

Comment: And kindly do tell us if it's working or not

Comment: @Mirzaei This might not be the right question but can you tell me how are you running your project?

Comment: Ctrl+F11 in eclipse. Or Right click on project B Run as java app...

Comment: All of my Runs are in eclipse IDE.

Comment: @Mirzaei Can you post you `main` method? Specially line 11?

Comment: line 11 is :cmp.main(new String[]{"F:\\arshad droos\\Thesis\\secureBranch\\personalblog\\build","F:\\arshad droos\\Thesis\\secureBranch"});

Comment: @Mirzaei Sorry but it's not readable. Edit your post & put this code. Do not forget to highlight line 11.

Comment: import jspParser.jspCompiler;  <br/>public class maintst {  public static void main(String[] args)  throws Exception {  
jspCompiler cmp=new  jspCompiler();  **cmp.main(new String[]{"F:\\arshad droos\\Thesis\\secureBranch\\personalblog\\build","F:\\arshad droos\\Thesis\\secureBranch"});**  
 }

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browsing the code of [Apache Tomcat](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/trunk/java/org/apache/) i could not find the find `org.apache.tools.ant.util.FileUtils`. Since running from eclipse works, this probably means is that **Project A** has some jar in the build path which has this file. Find it, put in in the build path of **Project B** and things should work.

Comment: Yes it is one of the project A's Dependent jar[ant jar]. So ant jar don't put it A's jar file? I open created A.jar and open .classpath.  see this line: **<classpathentry kind="lib" path="libs/ant-1.8.1.jar"/>**  
and A.jar contain libs/ant-1.8.1.jar file!!!

Comment: Yes It WORK. Thank you very mutch.  But I can't used A.jar without adding dependent jars?

Comment: You have to add all the dependencies. Maybe there is a way for eclipse to export the project and all dependencies, but I don't know of it.

Comment: Is it mater.But but I can't used exported jar stand alone rarely.

Comment: Yes thank you. It help to solve my problem.But not completely. Can I used **A.jar stand alone** in project B **without** adding ant-1.8.1.jar(A's dependent jar file which there is in A.jar content) to class path?

Comment: No you can't.  And I did solve your initial problem, so what you did was rude.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't want be rude Or disrespect to any one. Sorry again. It may be caused of my bad English knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse has a **[fatjar](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fjep/)** named **plugin**. After installing this jar to eclipse plugins(Copy past jar file to eclipse's plugin directory) In **Export** menu select jar fat. In this way size of exported jar is big But **Standalone**.

Thank you.